# Pandas - how to combine multiple dataframe from text files and save to each output files

Tags: python, pandas, blob

How can I combine files with the following conditions

**1.Product files**: I have product files in the same directory with following name
product1.txt, product2.txt, product3.txt, ..., productn.txt

**2.Order files**: I have order files in the same directory with following name
order1.txt, order2.txt, order3.txt, ..., ordern.txt

I want to read dataframe from each **product files** and compare with each **order files**
to find the same ID from each order files
**e.g.** 
**1.** if we can matching all product IDs in **product1.txt** with product ID in **order1.txt**, **order5.txt**, **order20.txt** then we combine them and save as the new output file and remove **product1.txt** from the directory
**2.** if we cannot matching all product IDs in **product2.txt** with the order files then skip it and wait for the next set of order files and daily recheck all order files in the directory
**3.** check the next product files...

Any advice or guidance would be greatly appreciated..!!

Comment: How big are the files? Are ids for each product file unique? What is the relationship between product and order?

Comment: "if we cannot matching all product IDs in" -- by saying all products, do you mean the acceptance criteria is to match ALL of the IDs from a product<n>.txt? What if you get 5 / 10 product IDs?

Comment: @Smurphy0000 about 50 - 5K rows, IDs for each product file are unique. One-to-One.
if we can match all ids in product<n>.txt then we create a new output file and remove product<n>.txt from the directory

Comment: @Shahidur we'll skip it and wait for the next set of order files for a recheck all order files in the directory if we can match all ids in product<n>.txt then we create a new output file and remove product<n>.txt from the directory